# Unable to remove an element inside n editable div using backspace - Jquery

Tags: html, contenteditable

I got this html

```
<div contenteditable="true"> Hey <a class="tgt" contenteditable="false">harry</a> great </div>
```

When in `firefox` I am unable to remove the `a.tgt` using `backspace`. Gets removed in all other browser except firefox

Whats the problem?

Comment: are you sure? I have tested in last version of FF and this code is working

Comment: no its doesn't...! (atleast for me)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This may be helpful for some. I ran into the same problem.

Instead of this:
    `<div contenteditable="true"> Hey <a class="tgt" contenteditable="false">harry</a> great </div>`

You can have this:
    `<div contenteditable="true"> Hey <a class="tgt" contenteditable="false">harry</a><span class="remove"></span> great </div>`

You can use javascript (using jquery in this case) to detect the deletion of .remove and remove your uneditable div at the same time:

```
// you can wrap this in an if statement and only execute in firefox
$('.remove').on("DOMNodeRemoved", function() { 
    $(this).prev(".tgt").remove();
});
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: amazing and so simple) Thank you

Answer (score -1):

try to wrap `<a>` html into **span** tag with attribute **contenteditable=true**

```
<div contenteditable="true"> Hey <a class="tgt" contenteditable="false"> <span contentEditable="true">harry</span></a> great</div>
```